# Network Bonding Ethernet and Wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, ethernet, network-bonding

I am trying to bond my Ethernet (`eth0`) and Wifi (`wlan0`) connection to increase aggregate bandwidth. (They are both on different networks with different bandwidth allocations.)

So far I've attempted to use the `ifenslave-2.6` package, but any change I made to `/etc/network/interfaces` resulted in networking not initialized on boot which lead to a 5 minute boot time and still no networking. Additionally, I tried using the built in network manager, and I think I was able to add the `eth0` interface, but I couldn't add the `wlan0` interface.

Those were the two solutions I was able to find online, but I couldn't get either to work successfully.

Comment: For those landing here in 2019+, Ubuntu network configuration is handled by Netplan these days. Interface bonding can be set up by adding entries to the `bonds` section of `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` as described here: https://netplan.io/examples#configuring-interface-bonding